# American money specifics in writing a check

Tags: word-choice, american-english, numbers

why can you write a check for twenty-nine hundred or thirty-one hundred but not one for thirty hundred?  it seems strange that the numbers before and after are accepted but not thirty hundred must be written out three thousand in order for a bank to cash it.

Comment: Hello Eleanor. I'd bet that there are some banks that _would_ accept it from a favoured customer. However, this is a matter of banks' use of English, which will doubtless follow their own protocols, rather than being about general English usage.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about bank-ese.

Comment: Increasing numbers of retail outlets no longer accept cheques in the UK, so I may have missed my chance to write one that large. But I'd have written *two thousand nine hundred pounds [only]* anyway. I'd only use *[number greater than 9] **hundred*** in contexts where [number] would normally be contextually expected to be 24 or less - as in meeting a [twelve hundred pound gorilla](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22twelve+hundred+pound+gorilla%22) ... [at ten hundred hours](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22at+ten+hundred+hours%22).

Comment: @FF If a twelve hundred pound gorilla presented the cheque, it'd be accepted.

Comment: If you wrote a cheque for thirty-hundred dollars... ALL banks would accept it. As long as the implied meaning in the words reflects the numbers, you'll be fine.

Comment: I'm writing my next $1000 cheque as ten-hundred.

Comment: I would never write a check for "twentynine hundred dollars".  Rather, it would be "two thousand nine hundred dollars".  (But I have never head of a bank refusing a check because the amount was written out in non-idiomatic terms, so long as the written amount and the digital amount matched.)

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing of the habits of American banks. But it is the case in general that informal English allows "twenty-nine hundred" and "thirty-one hundred", but not "thirty hundred".

As with almost all "why" questions about language, the answer is "because that's the way it is". But if you want a rationalisation, I would say that it is because "three thousand" is in some clear way simpler than "thirty hundred", whereas "three thousand one hundred" is less simple than "thirty-one hundred".